# Problem running Dask on AWS Sagemaker and AWS Fargate

Tags: dask, amazon-sagemaker, dask-distributed, aws-fargate

I am trying to setup a cluster on AWS to run distributed sklearn model training with dask. To get started, I was trying to follow this tutorial which I hope to tweak: https://towardsdatascience.com/serverless-distributed-data-pre-processing-using-dask-amazon-ecs-and-python-part-1-a6108c728cc4

I have managed to push the docker container to AWS ECR and then launch a  CloudFormation template to build a cluster on AWS Fargate. The next step in the tutorial is to launch an AWS Sagemaker Notebook. I have tried this but something is not working because when I run the commands I get errors (see image). **What might the problem be? Could it be related to the VPC/subnets? Is it related to AWS Sagemaker internet access?** (I have tried enabling and disabling this).

[image]

Expected Results: dask to update, scaling up of the Fargate cluster to work.

Actual Results: none of the above.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when running through the same tutorial, DaskSchedulerService takes too long to complete. The creation was initiated but never finished in CloudFormation.
After 5-6 hours i've got the following:

DaskSchedulerService    CREATE_FAILED Dask-Scheduler did not stabilize.

The workers did not run, and, consequently, it was not possible to connect to the Client.

Comment: And then I have turned to this tutorial to launch Dask in Fargate, which was successful to some extend. https://gist.github.com/jacobtomlinson/ee5ba79228e42bcc9975faf0179c3d1a